# CruiseControl And MSTest: Getting The Build To Fail If A Test Fails

Tags: mstest, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to integrate MSTest (Visual Studio 2010 version) into Cruise Control.  I can get the Test Report to show up in the Build Report, including showing tests that failed.  However, even though tests are failing, the CruiseControl build still 'succeeds' (for instance, in CCTray, the build 'goes green').  In the Build Web Page, it says 'Suites run: 0', 'Tests run: 0', etc.

I would like it so that if a test fails, the build fails (i.e., 'goes red').

I have searched all over the web, and followed every piece of advice I can find, to no avail.  Any help and/or advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that `msbuild.exe` returns a `"true"` exit code ($?) on test completion (rather than test passed). You need to examine the *`.trx` results file for the `ResultsSummary` section (specifically the counters `"passed"` and `"executed"`).

e.g. `Jenkins` has a way of converting *`.trx` to it's own (`jUnit`) format for interpreting these.

I've got a batch script which runs MSTEST specifying the output file while is then checked with the following for failures and then exits with a non-zero status (which will let Jenkins know that the test failed):

```
findstr "testsFailed=""[^0]""" "C:\Jenkins\workspace\YOUR_PROJECT\YOUR_RESULTS.trx" >"C:\Jenkins\workspace\YOUR_PROJECT\YOUR_RESULTS.out" && exit 1
```